# Loading store with params

Tags: sencha-touch, store

What I am trying to do is load store with params like below so I only get the first ten items of my store.

```
app.stores.actualites.load({
    params : {
         start:0,
         limit:10,
    },
    callback : function(records, operation, success) {
         app.loadmask.hide();
    }
});
```

But this is not working, it returns all the 18 store items.

If I put the start param to 1, it will return 17 items, so this param is working but not the other.

**Update : Store code**

```
app.stores.actualites = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'app.models.Actualites',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: app.stores.baseAjaxURL + '&jspPage=%2Fajax%2FlistActualites.jsp',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'actualite',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            idProperty: 'blogEntryInfosId'
        }
    }
});
```

The weird thing here is when I try the URL in a browser and add &start=0&limit=1 it works just fine...

**Update : Try with extraParams**

I also tried to do it with extraParams but this still doesn't work

```
app.stores.actualites.getProxy().extraParams.start = 1;
app.stores.actualites.getProxy().extraParams.limit = 2;
app.stores.actualites.load({
    callback : function(records, operation, success) {
        app.loadmask.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give code which processes this load request on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound weird, but I changed to name of the param 'limit' to 'stop' both on the client and the server and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

The pagination functionality has to be actually implemented at your server side. Sencha will only maintain the pages and will send you proper `start` and `limit` values. You need to access these values at your server side script and return appropriate results depending on those.

If you are using a list, then you can use Sencha's inbuilt ListPaging plugin which takes care of the start/limit parameter in its own.

Comment: Yes, but it works fine on a browser when I add &start=0&limit=1 ... See my update

Comment: Ok, then I think, because store load() function takes the Proxy config, you need to use "extraParams" instead of "params".

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like that:

```
app.stores.actualites.getProxy().setExtraParams({
                        start:1,
                        limit:2
                    })
```